# Return min and max of a subdocument property

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Suppose I have the following collection:

```
{
    "title": "foo1",
    "description: "bar1",
    "foobars": [
        {
            "title": "foobar1",
            "time": {
                "$date": "2013-10-04T19:53:54.714Z"
            }
        },
        {
            "title": "foobar2",
            "time": {
                "$date": "2013-10-06T19:53:54.714Z"
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

How would I query (using Mongoose) to find the min and max `time` value for all `foobars` for all documents. From the documentation it seems like something like this would be the way to do it, but this isn't working:

```
FooModel.aggregate({ $group: { _id: null, maxTime: { $max: '$foobars.time' }}}, callback);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$unwind` `foobars` before you group:

```js
FooModel.aggregate(
    { $unwind: '$foobars' },
    { $group: { _id: null, maxTime: { $max: '$foobars.time' }}}, 
    callback);
```